# How to make runProguard work for the android-library Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-library, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to run ProGuard on release build of my Android library. Below is my `build.gradle` file that is within my project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

Running `gradlew clean` or `gradlew build` returns the following error:

`> Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_25r1m0a3etn5cudtt5odlegprd$_run_closure2_closure10@5f3306ad] on project`

It seems that plugin `android-library` is missing the `buildTypes` method. If I change `apply plugin` to `android`, `gradlew` runs successfully. However, this is a library project and I would like to keep it so. Other parts my my `gradle.build` (not mentioned here) rely on the project being a library.

Is there any way to make the `android-library` plugin run ProGuard on build?

Comment: I think the idea is to run ProGuard once for all the code that comprises the final app, not for each library individually.

Comment: I am creating an SDK jar for distribution. I would like public functions to be visible, but private variables and functions to not be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue by taking `release` out of `buildTypes` like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }

    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
}
```

Also note that I added another `proguardFile` under `release`. This fixed another issue I was having after solving the initial `buildTypes` problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you added the other proguardFile and why you needed to do so?

Comment: I added it straight to the root of the project directory (where the `build.gradle` file is. The file can be used to configure various options (for example, which functions/classes/variables should not be "guarded"). A manual is available here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Ah, I get it.  The point I was missing is that you *moved* the release block so it is at the same level where releaseTypes used to be in build.gradle